# Pipeline is working same project with multibranch pipeline is not working

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, multibranch-pipeline

I have created a pipeline project with a bitbucket git project. It is checking out the Jenkins file using https://Username@bitbucket.org/myproject.git

No problems there.

I have created a multi branch pipeline project to the same bitbucket git project. I used the same credentials as the single pipeline project but now it is NOT checking out the Jenkins (or other) files.
It keeps complaining about: "could not read Password for 'https://Username@bitbucket.org': terminal prompts disabled"

I tried to use the SSH variant but that does not work at all even for the single branch pipeline project it is causing problems so that might be a completely different problem.

Is there a difference between single branch pipeline and a multi branch pipeline I need to know wit regards to user credentials?

If more information is needed the please let me now.